# Writing large dynamic arrays/objects to text formatted log files

Tags: php, arrays, magento, object, logging

For a few years I have been using Magento as my ecommerce site platform.

But I sometimes get really fed up when I see lack of PHP Functions, like `print_r` or `var_dump`, to handle writing large object/array to a log file(when printing this much data on Browser is already out of question).

For example when I have to check(debug what is it's outline and what data it holds) a large collection object(or object containing a lot of other objects due to dependencies) like `category-collection` or `product-collection`, if I run below code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
```

or

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
Mage::log(print_r($collection, true), null, 'developer.log');
```

Then many times I get error `Allowed memory size of ######## bytes exhausted ...`, especially when doing live projects(live websites hosted on Shared servers).

So in wake of this I really need a core-php suggestion about how to write large object/arrays like Magento collections to text log files without PHP Engine running out of memory and without needing to install Xdebug or other external utilities.

How(if I can) can I use `buffering` or `string splitting` in this scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you do not need the entire collection entity logged into a file, but `$collection->getItems()`. 
There might be recursions in properties of your collections objects, so they cannot not be properly var_dump'ed.

Comment: But does every Collection has function `getItems()` defined ? Sometimes I have found some `$collection` objects has no `getItems()` available, or how to get each and every function a collection can Call including basic getters and setters ? How to find that out ? `get_class_methods` doesn't help in this.

Comment: `getItems` is not a magic method in Magento collections.
The easiest plain-PHP way is `if (is_callable($collection, 'getItems')) {...}`
More elegant way is to check `if ($collection instanceof Varien_Data_Collection) {...}`